# Checkout won't go to payment page after new shipping region added

Tags: expresso-store

I recently added Australia to the shipping regions allowed (formerly was just the UK). With a UK address + United Kingdom chosen as the country for billing/shipping, the checkout process works fine, and submitting the details brings the buyer to paypal. With an Australian address + Australia chosen as the country for billing/shipping, submitting does nothing at all - it just returns the same page. Any idea why?

Comment: This would probably be better suited on the EE specific site.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to diagnosis without seeing your template. My initial thought is that you currently have inline errors turned on in your template and the form has an error in but you have not templates the  `{error:field_name}'` for the field in question. Since it is only happening for Australia I would go further to say you are using the default shipping method for shipping and you do not currently have a rule setup that handles your desired shipping location.

To fix make sure that you have inline error handling turned off in that template. This will present you with the standard EE error page to help diagnosis.

If you are using the default shipping method make sure you have a rule that handles Australia.